# Gem dependency issues: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, cloud9

I'm trying to set up MongoDB on a Rails app in Cloud9.
I've installed Rails 5.0.1 and MongoDB, but problems are arrising with my gemfile.

This is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.3'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

When I run 'bundle install' I get the following error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
>
> In Gemfile:
>
> mongoid (>= 5.1.3, ~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
>      activemodel (~> 4.0)
>
> rails (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
>         activemodel (= 5.0.1)
>
> rails (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
>         activemodel (= 5.0.1)

Comment: What happens if you run bundle update?

Comment: I get the same error message.

Comment: You have to allow mongoid for bigger version. 5.1.3 will only work for Rails 4+. `~>4.0` means `4+ < 5`

Comment: Ok I changed the mongoid gem version to 6.1.0 and after running bundle update everything works. Thank you!!! :)